# Create a string for each item of the dataframe and then google it

Tags: python, pandas, pyautogui

I am trying to make a loop to create a string for each element of my dataframe and then search it on google.

For that I am using pandas and pyautogui. The issue is that my code is not writing anything inside the search bar.

```
import pyautogui
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(["apple", "orange", "lemon", "banana"])

def test():
    for index in range(len(df)):
        string = df.loc[index]
        print(string)
        chrome = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("c.png")
        pyautogui.click(chrome)
        search = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("search.png")
        pyautogui.click(search)
        pyautogui.write(string)
        
test()
```

How can I fix it to make the code open my chrome, click on the search bar and then search for each one of the items that I have in my dataframe?

Comment: Please describe your motivation for using this fragile search technique. Is there a reason that [obtaining an API key](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) does not fit your use case?

Comment: I am learning python, and that is one of the first codes that I have ever written.

I know that is pretty weak, but I want it to make work to feel that I am evolving.

Comment: Is your `click(chrome)` supposed to launch the browser?  In most cases, you have to double-click to launch, not just click.  And then you have to WAIT for it to appear.  It's likely your loop is completing before the browser is even running.  There are VASTLY better ways to do this; you make make web requests directly using the `requests` module.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If I use pynput.controller I am able to type it on the search bar.

```
import pyautogui
import pandas as pd 
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(["apple", "orange", "lemon", "banana"])
    
    def test():
        for index in df:
            chrome = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("c.png") #opens chrome window
            pyautogui.click(chrome)
            search = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("search.png") #click on the search bar
            pyautogui.click(search)
            keyboard.type(index)

            
    test()
```